# Convert scientific notation to decimal

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do the challenge on http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/problems/problems.php?id=2 and I'm having problems converting scientific notation to decimal notation, which I need to add the exponent together:

Here is my code so far:

```
#define FIRST 2
#define SECOND 20

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Give variables initial setting
    int total = 0;
    float powanswer = 0;

    // Get rid of scientific notation for large numbers
    stringstream ss;
    ss.setf(ios::fixed);
    ss << pow(FIRST,SECOND);
    ss >> powanswer;


    // Output
    // Expected: 2^20 = 1048576 => 1+0+4+8+5+7+6 => 31
    // Outcome: 2^20 = 1.04858e+06  => 1+.+0+4+8+5+8+e+++0+6 => 32
    cout << FIRST << "^" << SECOND << " = " << powanswer << "  => ";


    // Convert power int to string
    string ResultText = "";
    stringstream convert;
    convert << powanswer;
    ResultText = convert.str();

    // Loop over total
    for (int x=0; x<ResultText.size(); x++)
    {

        // Convert character to integer
        int ResultNum = 0;
        stringstream convert;
        convert << ResultText[x];
        convert >> ResultNum;
        total+=ResultNum;

        // Output
        cout << ResultText[x];
        ResultText.size()-1 == x ? cout << " => " : cout << "+";

    }
    cout << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried searching everywhere on how to convert it, and I read I can use << fixed << on the stream, or .setf(ios::fixed) but neither seems to be working for me and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

As marked in the code, here is the current output:

```
2^20 = 1.04858e+06  => 1+.+0+4+8+5+8+e+++0+6 => 32
```

What I want and expect to see is:

```
2^20 = 1048576 => 1+0+4+8+5+7+6 => 31
```

Edit: Spelling mistake

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is. Please pose a question so that it may be answered. (Such as "I'm getting these errors/this result when I try to use `.setf(ios::fixed)`. Why is that?", for example.)

Comment: I want to change the scientific notation of the number to decimal notation, but the change isn't taking place as I would expect it to. It stays as scientific notation.

Comment: I still don't see an explicit question. I don't mean to be nit-picking, but a piece of advice for you is that a lot of people on this site consider it extremely important that questions are well-formed. I see you already have an accepted answer to this question, so all is well this time. :-) But a word of caution: Questions get down-voted for less sometimes. I do believe a question can become closed for "not an actual question" as well. Glad to hear your problem was fixed! Take care! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `powanswer` is a `float`, but you want to print it as an `integer`?

How about something like:

```
int powanswer_int = (int) powanswer;
cout << FIRST << "^" << SECOND << " = " << powanswer_int << "  => ";
```

And use the `powanswer_int` later as well.

Comment: I actually had it as an int previously but changed it to float for testing but forgot to change it back. But using (int)powanswer solved the problem. Thanks!